# Asyncpg: KeyError '0'

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, keyerror, asyncpg

I'm working with asyncpg to insert a list of items into postgres. When I run the function, I get `"KeyError: 0"` with no additional context.

Has anyone encountered this?

```
import asyncpg
import os
    
cls = [list_of_columns]
pg_key = os.environ["PG_CONN"]
conn = await asyncpg.connect(pg_key)
await conn.copy_records_to_table('ppg', records=d, columns=cls)
await conn.close()
```

Comment: Does `cls` have a `0` in it?

Comment: the error message should contain some other indication, like the line number of where the error happens. Please write it into the question.

Comment: @L-M answer updated. Does this answer your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with asyncpg.

You get `"KeyError: 0"` because you are trying to obtain a value from a dictionary which does not have the key that you typed in your code.

So my guess is that somewhere in your code you are trying to access the key `0` of a dictionary which does not contain that key, something like

```
my_var = my_dict[0]
```

Most of the times, one gets this error because 
**one iterates on a list variable to get numeric values and then tries to pass them to the dictionary**, 
as if it were possible to access the dictionary values by calling them as they were stored inside a list 
- that is, treating by mistake the dictionary as if it were a list - 
so by positional argument, rather than by their keys.

### Example:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"alpha": 0.5, "beta": 0.05, "gamma": 0.005} 
for i in my_list:
    print(my_dict[i])
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
> KeyError: 0
> ```

but what you wanted was probably

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"alpha": 0.5, "beta": 0.05, "gamma": 0.005} 
for i in my_dict:
    print(my_dict[i])
```

> ```
> 0.5
> 0.05
> 0.005
> ```

And just to be clear, here is what happens when you inspect the value of `i` in the two snippets:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"alpha": 0.5, "beta": 0.05, "gamma": 0.005} 
for i in my_list:
    print("i =",i)
    print(my_dict[i])
```

> ```
> i = 0
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
> KeyError: 0
> ```

---

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"alpha": 0.5, "beta": 0.05, "gamma": 0.005} 
for i in my_dict:
    print("i =",i)
    print(my_dict[i])
```

> ```
> i = alpha
> 0.5
> i = beta
> 0.05
> i = gamma
> 0.005
> ```